# "Open with" dialog for custom file format

Tags: php, file-type, open-with

I have an file `file.magicExt` which is just a text file (utf-8), e.g.:

```
hello
```

I have an `index.php`:

```
<?php

echo '<a href="file.magicExt">file</a>';
```

*What I would like is* to show "open with" dialog when user click on "file" link.

*Instead* the browser (Firefox, Chrome) shows the file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done with such `file.php`:

```
<?php

// We'll be outputting a .magicExt
header('Content-Type: application/magicExt');

// It will be called downloaded.magicExt
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.magicExt"');

// The .magicExt source is in original.magicExt
readfile('original.magicExt');
```

Based on [PHP header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

and that `index.php`:

```
echo '<a href="file.php">file</a>';
```